# How struct spring batch multiple reader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I new in springbatch user.
Below data structure is some of sample structre.

user table

```
| id | name| age|
| -------- | -------------- |-------------- |
| 1    | park            |12            |
| 2   | kim            |13|
```

user_service_history table

```
| id | user_id| status|
| -------- | -------------- |-------------- |
| 1    | 1            |create            |
| 2   | 1            |conenct|
| 3    | 1            |delete            |
| 4   | 2            |conenct|
```

Can spring batch do this flow?
I tried step in two reader, But spring batch only allow step in one reader... :(

```
Job{
 step{
  reader{
   //this reader read to id and name
     List<user> userList=select id , name from user
  },
  processor{/* do some process userList */},
  writer{/* do nothing */}
 },
step{
  reader(List<user> userList){ // this parameter is delivered from above processor
   //this reader read to user_service_history
     select user_id,status from user_service_history joined user where in userList
  }, 
 processor{/* do some process */}
  writer{/* final write wanted data */}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two readers for that. You have a few options:

- use a single reader with a query that joins data from both tables
- create a custom reader that reads data as needed from both tables
- use the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders), where a reader reads items from one table and a processor enriches those items from the other table. Items here would be users.